# How to set width of UICollectionView on rotation with auto layout programmatically swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I've set up a collection view with self sizing cells using auto layout. However, when I rotate the device the collection view still uses the portrait width and gets cut off. I am using flow layout and not the sizeForItemAt method.

Here is my main view controller:

```
import UIKit

class HomeController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

    let homeCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    homeCollectionView.dataSource = self
    homeCollectionView.delegate = self
    homeCollectionView.backgroundColor = .orange

    homeCollectionView.register(CellTypeOne.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellType1")

    self.view.addSubview(homeCollectionView)
    homeCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
homeCollectionView.leadingAnchor

.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    homeCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    homeCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    homeCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true

  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contents.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    // code for specific type of cells
  }

  let contents: [ContentType] = []
```

Also, here is one of my cells:

```
import UIKit

class CellType1: UICollectionViewCell {

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupViews()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  }

  var content: Content? {
    didSet {
      sectionTextView.text = content?.sectionView
    }
  }

  let sectionTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
//    textView.backgroundColor = .orange
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 20, 0)
    textView.text = "This is a Section text"
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: .heavy)
    textView.textColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 76/255, blue: 77/255, alpha: 1.0)
    textView.isEditable = false
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return textView
  }()

  func setupViews() {
    addSubview(sectionTextView)

    let widthAnchorConstraint = sectionTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 16)
    widthAnchorConstraint.identifier = "sectionTextView Width Anchor Constraint"
    widthAnchorConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)
    widthAnchorConstraint.isActive = true

    let topAnchorConstraint = sectionTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor)
    topAnchorConstraint.identifier = "sectionTextView Top Anchor Constraint"
    topAnchorConstraint.isActive = true

    let leftAnchorConstraint = sectionTextView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor)
    leftAnchorConstraint.identifier = "sectionTextView Left Anchor Constraint"
    leftAnchorConstraint.isActive = true

    let rightAnchorConstraint = sectionTextView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor)
    rightAnchorConstraint.identifier = "sectionTextView Right Anchor Constraint"
    rightAnchorConstraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
    rightAnchorConstraint.isActive = true

    let bottomAnchorConstraint = sectionTextView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
    bottomAnchorConstraint.identifier = "sectionTextView Bottom Anchor Constraint"
    bottomAnchorConstraint.isActive = true
  }
}
```

I already had tried using Auto Layout as Sh_Khan's suggested. I updated the code above. However, when I rotate, the collection view get's updated but the cells still stay the size of a portrait width device. I added a screenshot.

[image: Landscape screenshot]
I removed the content with red marking

Could anyone point me in the right direction seeing as how invalidateLayout() doesn't work on flow layout.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Make use of size classes. There you can set the layout for different all sizes.

Comment: @SHISHIRRAMIN, I can't get this to work. How do I do this. I tried it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459702/update-contentview-of-uicollectionviewcell-when-changing-size-classes-programati

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that giving the collection  a frame when creating makes it keep it even after rotation , you can try to use autoLayout

```
    self.view.addSubview(homeCollectionView)
    homeCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false 
    homeCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    homeCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    homeCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    homeCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: I updated my question with my new findings. Still not working as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this without using auto-layout as well, The view controller tells you when its view gets new frame (when rotated e.g.) through `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` which is a good place to set all your frame/position related properties.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    homeCollectionView.frame = view.frame

    // Set frames of other views that may have change 
}
```

And for the cell there is `override layoutSubviews()`

Comment: This doesn't work. When I implement this code, the collection view gets aligned to the left and still uses the portrait width and the rest of the screen is blank.

Comment: Hey, try the viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: Still the same effect. A full width collection view. But cells not updating to their new width.

Comment: They have the very similar method called layoutSubviews() that you should override too

Comment: Still no effect. I added the layoutSubviews() method to the cell class and tried updating constraints as I want to keep using auto layout. No luck, also when I try using frame.width and update it then, still no luck..